# How do I fix wp super cache error message?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using wp super cache in WordPress. After months of using it, i tried deactivating. But after activating it again, i am prompted with the error below below:

> WP-Cache Config Sample File See wp-cache.php for author details. */
>   $wp_cache_mobile_browsers = '2.0 MMP, 240x320, 400X240, AvantGo,
>   BlackBerry, Blazer, Cellphone, Danger, //Added by WP-Cache Manager ?>
>   Error: Your cache directory () did not exist and couldn’t be created
>   by the web server. Check permissions.

**I am currently using WP Super Cache Version 1.4.8**

Do you know how can I fix this or do I just need to update to a recent version?

Comment: did you `Check permissions` yet?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by checking my wp-cache-config.php. Upon checking  wp-cache-config.php, I saw that the contents became binary codes.

I was able to revert this by using the code that was saved from my localhost server.

Comment: I had a similar problem: during a migration, this file was copied, preserving the previous path, which obviously turned invalid in the new host. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if you change the `$cache_path` variable to use `ABSPATH` instead, this will be fixed.  I don't know why WP Super Cache would not use this wordpress definition instead tbh.  So it should be changed to look like this in the wp-content/wp-cache-config.php file:

```
$cache_path = ABSPATH . '/wp-content/cache/';
```

Comment: Why would this be better than `$cache_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/cache/';` This makes the assumption that `WP_CONTENT_DIR` is the default. It exists as a changeable constant to allow options.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
mkdir wp-content/cache/
chmod 777 wp-content/cache/
```